# Задание options для полигона по клику с внешней кнопки Яндекс карты

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

Пытаюсь по кнопке изменять видимость полигонов на карте.
Событие .options.set не срабатывает, не видит полигоны как объекты

https://jsfiddle.net/redcornerspb/th2oj3qL/8/

```
ymaps.ready(init);
var myMap;
var myMap2;
function init() {
    myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: [59.951671, 30.330581],
            zoom: 10
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        });
// Оформление всплывашек
HintLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass( "<div class='my-hint2'>" +
            "<b>{{ properties.hintContent }}</b>" +
            "</div>", {
                getShape: function () {
                    var el = this.getElement(),
                        result = null;
                    if (el) {
                        var firstChild = el.firstChild;
                        result = new ymaps.shape.Rectangle(
                            new ymaps.geometry.pixel.Rectangle([
                                [0, 0],
                                [firstChild.offsetWidth, firstChild.offsetHeight]
                            ])
                        );
                    }
                    return result;
                }
            }
        );

    var myGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
        // Описываем геометрию геообъекта.
        geometry: {
            // Тип геометрии - "Многоугольник".
            type: "Polygon",
            // Указываем координаты вершин многоугольника.
            coordinates: [
                // Координаты вершин внешнего контура.
                [
                   [    59.981239087147 ,   30.27609962600384   ],
                    [   59.981196074998856  ,   30.27876037734661   ],
                    [   59.9815831822278    ,   30.280691567837287  ],
                    [   59.98194877933121   ,   30.2827729620328    ],
                    [   59.98227136165508   ,   30.285970155178543  ],
                    [   59.98246490953142   ,   30.288502160488605  ],
                    [   59.98261544599256   ,   30.29172081130653   ],
                    [   59.98267996140015   ,   30.294209901272357  ],
                    [   59.982572435647775  ,   30.297213975369072  ],
                    [   59.9824003937033    ,   30.29996055740032   ],
                    [   59.981841251207015  ,   30.303479615627847  ],
                    [   59.981131556689576  ,   30.30712741988811   ],
                    [   59.980604652402164  ,   30.310067120968437  ],
                    [   59.98003472605614   ,   30.313178483425705  ],
                    [   59.97971212185701   ,   30.316440049587765  ],
                    [   59.97908841150119   ,   30.319014970242065  ],
                    [   59.97829262597742   ,   30.321675721584835  ],
                    [   59.97746455850594   ,   30.323692742764035  ],
                    [   59.976550433928956  ,   30.32528061050089   ],
                    [   59.97556099995591   ,   30.326954308926144  ],
                    [   59.974399452665565  ,   30.328971330105393  ],
                    [   59.97302275107516   ,   30.33025879043249   ],
                    [   59.97164599206568   ,   30.331374589382744  ],
                    [   59.97044128081365   ,   30.332576219021394  ],
                    [   59.96897835804662   ,   30.333606187283127  ],
                    [   59.96798869704954   ,   30.334464494167882  ],
                    [   59.96596625406481   ,   30.335151139675695  ],
                    [   59.963943687163194  ,   30.33566612380656   ],
                    [   59.96192099636207   ,   30.335923615872005  ],
                    [   59.96028553873831   ,   30.33630985397011   ],
                    [   59.95869304164777   ,   30.336781922756714  ],
                    [   59.956971336760866  ,   30.337554398952996  ],
                    [   59.955141926972125  ,   30.338884774624383  ],
                    [   59.95465765446311   ,   30.33959287780425   ],
                    [   59.9540011848603    ,   30.34047264236114   ],
                    [   59.95325860514969   ,   30.340601388393846  ],
                    [   59.95260210775141   ,   30.339871827541877  ],
                    [   59.95170881983031   ,   30.33682483810095   ],
                    [   59.9509016111822    ,   30.331803742825112  ],
                    [   59.94986835530316   ,   30.32828468459753   ],
                    [   59.949093392191536  ,   30.325538102566284  ],
                    [   59.9481892455934    ,   30.322362367092648  ],
                    [   59.94663922241132   ,   30.317555848537967  ],
                    [   59.94571347943315   ,   30.31425136703162   ],
                    [   59.94500300793608   ,   30.312663499294814  ],
                    [   59.94392650685457   ,   30.311204377590744  ],
                    [   59.942505471715236  ,   30.309916917263543  ],
                    [   59.940912117239534  ,   30.30751365798624   ],
                    [   59.93970628439915   ,   30.304509583889526  ],
                    [   59.93893108290631   ,   30.302578393398804  ],
                    [   59.93776824658451   ,   30.29850143569617   ],
                    [   59.936799185054824  ,   30.29605526107458   ],
                    [   59.935873166388724  ,   30.292750779568234  ],
                    [   59.93507633885499   ,   30.290175858913937  ],
                    [   59.93423641877732   ,   30.28717178481727   ],
                    [   59.93350416333466   ,   30.28391021865516   ],
                    [   59.93281496694135   ,   30.279447022854423  ],
                    [   59.93195345122776   ,   30.277172509609755  ],
                    [   59.930962680404065  ,   30.275176946102665  ],
                    [   59.92962724667013   ,   30.272838059841728  ],
                    [   59.928119434061394  ,   30.271464768826057  ],
                    [   59.926740802366666  ,   30.270520631252825  ],
                    [   59.9246942899427    ,   30.268932763515995  ],
                    [   59.92303544483996   ,   30.26811737197547   ],
                    [   59.92096715776155   ,   30.26700157302527   ],
                    [   59.919200393467975  ,   30.264769975124914  ],
                    [   59.91825233468623   ,   30.263053361355347  ],
                    [   59.918123051833966  ,   30.26073593276652   ],
                    [   59.91868327386725   ,   30.258332673489193  ],
                    [   59.91902802117505   ,   30.25567192214642   ],
                    [   59.92001914963477   ,   30.251981202541867  ],
                    [   59.92161351138359   ,   30.24743217605266   ],
                    [   59.922302941304906  ,   30.241939011990166  ],
                    [   59.924026453231384  ,   30.23816246169719   ],
                    [   59.92523285813594   ,   30.234385911404217  ],
                    [   59.926094548979066  ,   30.23129600661905   ],
                    [   59.92816251538927   ,   30.227176133572183  ],
                    [   59.928679486783494  ,   30.222026292263585  ],
                    [   59.929541087802285  ,   30.21807808059364   ],
                    [   59.93117806789334   ,   30.21395820754677   ],
                    [   59.93199652753072   ,   30.21365780013709   ],
                    [   59.931867298408534  ,   30.21164077895789   ],
                    [   59.9308980939358    ,   30.21214334215586   ],
                    [   59.93103812636333   ,   30.20929850850342   ],
                    [   59.928388811761636  ,   30.20944532801485   ],
                    [   59.928518174932016  ,   30.203215834713493  ],
                    [   59.929035381658686  ,   30.20157151485881   ],
                    [   59.93144826373044   ,   30.19261804970996   ],
                    [   59.93205229979472   ,   30.19119061159988   ],
                    [   59.94213252457718   ,   30.18164094167848   ],
                    [   59.94308375147014   ,   30.18073770779272   ],
                    [   59.94352207230666   ,   30.179274562775092  ],
                    [   59.94396809243775   ,   30.178236547886346  ],
                    [   59.944687876077765  ,   30.178048793255297  ],
                    [   59.94518010945688   ,   30.17921823638579   ],
                    [   59.943580983524804  ,   30.19014019149443   ],
                    [   59.950372153523254  ,   30.194474641262506  ],
                    [   59.95060686995215   ,   30.193187180935354  ],
                    [   59.951076297806786  ,   30.193358842312303  ],
                    [   59.95253173190499   ,   30.183230821072076  ],
                    [   59.95320395356737   ,   30.18288749831816   ],
                    [   59.95385959823991   ,   30.183059159695105  ],
                    [   59.9543960098232    ,   30.18426078933378   ],
                    [   59.95434959963445   ,   30.185462418972406  ],
                    [   59.95348191889849   ,   30.186835709988056  ],
                    [   59.95122987838053   ,   30.201941911159956  ],
                    [   59.9508585594725    ,   30.204001847683443  ],
                    [   59.951213734169876  ,   30.205782834469275  ],
                    [   59.951870259177575  ,   30.20558971542022   ],
                    [   59.952063985378985  ,   30.204345170437335  ],
                    [   59.95279582965621   ,   30.203916016994995  ],
                    [   59.953624516081284  ,   30.203958932339205  ],
                    [   59.95462536938002   ,   30.20443100112581   ],
                    [   59.95585218043809   ,   30.205203477322065  ],
                    [   59.956971336733844  ,   30.205954495846246  ],
                    [   59.958133497371904  ,   30.20713466781284   ],
                    [   59.95899433073709   ,   30.208465043484253  ],
                    [   59.958859826998456  ,   30.209505740582035  ],
                    [   59.95932789764275   ,   30.210374776302874  ],
                    [   59.96022097952969   ,   30.21151203292518   ],
                    [   59.96123239250762   ,   30.21378654616985   ],
                    [   59.963212089909675  ,   30.21618980544715   ],
                    [   59.96656869684799   ,   30.21618980544715   ],
                    [   59.96874170266887   ,   30.215503159939338  ],
                    [   59.969021386103364  ,   30.21395820754677   ],
                    [   59.969756888419695  ,   30.213309112965145  ],
                    [   59.97036329574373   ,   30.21266001838354   ],
                    [   59.97011320449365   ,   30.21136182922034   ],
                    [   59.97055960259979   ,   30.2106537260404    ],
                    [   59.97128028077678   ,   30.21043914931919   ],
                    [   59.97202783330045   ,   30.210138741909482  ],
                    [   59.97273234572975   ,   30.209924165188273  ],
                    [   59.97353902088615   ,   30.2100099958768    ],
                    [   59.97441558552093   ,   30.210203114925825  ],
                    [   59.97507702686444   ,   30.21099704879424   ],
                    [   59.975883644708944  ,   30.21224159377718   ],
                    [   59.97686231455832   ,   30.21421569961219   ],
                    [   59.977840955392935  ,   30.21593231338173   ],
                    [   59.979475543472134  ,   30.22099632400188   ],
                    [   59.98042184691536   ,   30.224515382229413  ],
                    [   59.98067992496484   ,   30.229579392849537  ],
                    [   59.98093800099118   ,   30.23309845107704   ],
                    [   59.981239087147 ,   30.236617509304573  ],
                    [   59.98138962917882   ,   30.23944992202429   ],
                    [   59.9817122169765    ,   30.242883149563372  ],
                    [   59.982099318145124  ,   30.247603837429605  ],
                    [   59.98229286702623   ,   30.251037064968635  ],
                    [   59.9824864147809    ,   30.253955308376828  ],
                    [   59.98248641478992   ,   30.25850433486614   ],
                    [   59.98248641478992   ,   30.26331085342082   ],
                    [   59.98235738307362   ,   30.26592868941933   ],
                    [   59.98192727373798   ,   30.268632356106338  ],
                    [   59.98156167638953   ,   30.27099270003943   ],
                    [   59.98123908713797   ,   30.273095551907097  ],
                    [   59.981239087147 ,   30.27609962600384   ],

                ],
                 []

            ],
            // Задаем правило заливки внутренних контуров по алгоритму "nonZero".
            fillRule: "nonZero"
         },
        // Описываем свойства геообъекта.
        properties:{
            // Содержимое балуна.
             hintContent: 'Доставка '
        }
    }, {
        // Описываем опции геообъекта.
        // Описываем опции геообъекта.
        // Цвет заливки.
        fillColor: '#1C5C38',
        strokeColor: '#6FCF97',
        // Общая прозрачность (как для заливки, так и для обводки).
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        // Ширина обводки.
        strokeWidth: 2,
       visible: true,
        hintLayout: HintLayout
    });

    // Добавляем многоугольник на карту.
    myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject);


    var myGeoObject4 = new ymaps.GeoObject({
        geometry: {
            type: "Polygon",
            coordinates: [
        [
           [    60.01718588340205   ,   30.46043011820965   ],
            [   60.01758330947494   ,   30.46123478091407   ],
            [   60.01866815085925   ,   30.462211104995482  ],
            [   60.0200644287746    ,   30.463648769027472  ],
            [   60.0213102883386    ,   30.464292499191046  ],
            [   60.0228138491908    ,   30.46352002299476   ],
            [   60.02423142942893   ,   30.46214673197914   ],
            [   60.025949626706385  ,   30.461889239913745  ],
            [   60.02955754923467   ,   30.461288425094406  ],
            [   60.032177340476764  ,   30.458198520309217  ],
            [   60.03402395331746   ,   30.454936954147133  ],
            [   60.036729268829205  ,   30.450817081100265  ],
            [   60.03827506359905   ,   30.448585483199885  ],
            [   60.0395631704603    ,   30.446353885299477  ],
            [   60.04058288597141   ,   30.445087882644458  ],
            [   60.04130203476397   ,   30.443821879989414  ],
            [   60.04231096330164   ,   30.444379779464516  ],
            [   60.04323399848103   ,   30.44536683238201   ],
            [   60.04394235676794   ,   30.44678303874187   ],
            [   60.04535902760369   ,   30.44875714457683   ],
            [   60.04625901022304   ,   30.45270123730651   ],
            [   60.047330672387865  ,   30.451838811481537  ],
            [   60.04851111409337   ,   30.451066335285226  ],
            [   60.05089333111578   ,   30.452182134235404  ],
            [   60.05207364502012   ,   30.45411332472615   ],
            [   60.05262086709967   ,   30.455679734790852  ],
            [   60.053323658575856  ,   30.456291278446244  ],
            [   60.05179466557309   ,   30.446946462238408  ],
            [   60.052653056368335  ,   30.443169911945432  ],
            [   60.05336121190084   ,   30.439007123554276  ],
            [   60.053640178086695  ,   30.43638928755574   ],
            [   60.053854765842765  ,   30.432655652607004  ],
            [   60.05368309575076   ,   30.429694493854573  ],
            [   60.05179466557309   ,   30.426003774250123  ],
            [   60.050077816792616  ,   30.4246304832345    ],
            [   60.050925522058904  ,   30.419695218647085  ],
            [   60.04936959055743   ,   30.4183648429757    ],
            [   60.04874719735829   ,   30.420510610187605  ],
            [   60.047502375641024  ,   30.42531712874231   ],
            [   60.04685848384666   ,   30.427119573200326  ],
            [   60.046171652055 ,   30.429694493854598  ],
            [   60.0445832986306    ,   30.432784398639736  ],
            [   60.04342418152744   ,   30.435402234638275  ],
            [   60.041492228978846  ,   30.43784840925989   ],
            [   60.03840086900638   ,   30.44008000716027   ],
            [   60.036339801068785  ,   30.44076665266808   ],
            [   60.03509450997479   ,   30.44119580611042   ],
            [   60.033935058698646  ,   30.44248326643762   ],
            [   60.031229513562074  ,   30.44445737227258   ],
            [   60.02848079562844   ,   30.44703229292683   ],
            [   60.02641910660191   ,   30.449178060138788  ],
            [   60.02328337379062   ,   30.4522679649239    ],
            [   60.02070583561536   ,   30.45510037764367   ],
            [   60.01718588340205   ,   30.46043011820965   ],              
            ],
        []
  ],
            fillRule: "nonZero"
        },
        properties:{
            hintContent:  'Доставка'
        }
    }, {
        fillColor: '#1C5C38',
        strokeColor: '#6FCF97',
        opacity: 0.5,
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        strokeWidth: 2,
        visible: true,
        hintLayout: HintLayout
    });
    myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject4);
//Оформление Пина
     MyIconContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
            '<div style="color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold;">$[properties.iconContent]</div>'
        ),

    myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([60.017089596047725, 30.434473], {
            hintContent: 'Мы находимся тут',
        }, {
             // Опции.
            iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
            //прописать путь до пина
            iconImageHref: 'pin.svg',
            iconImageSize: [20, 31],
            iconImageOffset: [-5, -38],
            iconContentLayout: MyIconContentLayout,
        hintLayout: HintLayout

        });

    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

}
function setVisible(){
    myGeoObject4.options.set({
        visible: false
    });
    myGeoObject1.options.set({
        visible: false
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#change-map').on('click', function() {
    init(setVisible());
  });
});
```

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Посмотрите ошибки, у вас они наверняка есть в консоли. Почему вы вызываете `init(setVisible());`? У вас `myGeoObject4` и `myGeoObject1` не существуют в функции `setVisible`.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем примере переменные myGeoObject* объявлены в функции init, их не видно в setVisible. Ещё там не подключен jquery. Сюда всё не влезает, вот полный работающий пример: https://jsfiddle.net/naivv/tmrvznkb/

Кстати, вы также можете использовать элемент управления "Кнопка" на карте. Вот ваш пример с кнопкой-переключателем на карте: https://jsfiddle.net/naivv/tbrL82cu/

```js
ymaps.ready(init);
var myMap;
var myMap2;
var myGeoObject, myGeoObject2, myGeoObject3, myGeoObject4;

function init() {
  myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: [59.951671, 30.330581],
    zoom: 10
  }, {
    searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
  });
  // Оформление всплывашек
  HintLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass("<div class='my-hint2'>" +
    "<b>{{ properties.hintContent }}</b>" +
    "</div>", {
      getShape: function() {
        var el = this.getElement(),
          result = null;
        if (el) {
          var firstChild = el.firstChild;
          result = new ymaps.shape.Rectangle(
            new ymaps.geometry.pixel.Rectangle([
              [0, 0],
              [firstChild.offsetWidth, firstChild.offsetHeight]
            ])
          );
        }
        return result;
      }
    }
  );

  myGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
    // Описываем геометрию геообъекта.
    geometry: {
      // Тип геометрии - "Многоугольник".
      type: "Polygon",
      // Указываем координаты вершин многоугольника.
      coordinates: [
        // Координаты вершин внешнего контура.
        [
          ],
        []

      ],
      // Задаем правило заливки внутренних контуров по алгоритму "nonZero".
      fillRule: "nonZero"
    },
    // Описываем свойства геообъекта.
    properties: {
      // Содержимое балуна.
      hintContent: 'Доставка '
    }
  }, {
    // Описываем опции геообъекта.
    // Описываем опции геообъекта.
    // Цвет заливки.
    fillColor: '#1C5C38',
    strokeColor: '#6FCF97',
    // Общая прозрачность (как для заливки, так и для обводки).
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.3,
    // Ширина обводки.
    strokeWidth: 2,
    visible: true,
    hintLayout: HintLayout
  });

  // Добавляем многоугольник на карту.
  myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject);

  myGeoObject2 = new ymaps.GeoObject({
    geometry: {
      type: "Polygon",
      coordinates: [
        [
        ],
        []

      ],
      fillRule: "nonZero"
    },
    properties: {
      hintContent: 'Доставка',

    },

  }, {
    fillColor: '#57266F',
    strokeColor: '#F1E7FF',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.3,
    strokeWidth: 2,
    visible: true,
    hintLayout: HintLayout
  });

  myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject2);

  myGeoObject3 = new ymaps.GeoObject({
    geometry: {
      type: "Polygon",
      coordinates: [
        [
        ],
        []
      ],

      fillRule: "nonZero"
    },
    properties: {
      hintContent: 'Доставка'
    }
  }, {
    fillColor: '#FD7669',
    strokeColor: '#FFDCD9',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.3,
    strokeWidth: 2,
    visible: true,
    hintLayout: HintLayout
  });

  myGeoObject3.events.add('click', function(e) {
    myGeoObject3.opacity.set({
      strokeOpacity: 0,
      fillOpacity: 0,
    });
  });

  myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject3);

  // Создаем многоугольник, используя класс GeoObject. Мурино
  myGeoObject4 = new ymaps.GeoObject({
    geometry: {
      type: "Polygon",
      coordinates: [
        [
        ],
        []
      ],
      fillRule: "nonZero"
    },
    properties: {
      hintContent: 'Доставка'
    }
  }, {
    fillColor: '#1C5C38',
    strokeColor: '#6FCF97',
    opacity: 0.5,
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.3,
    strokeWidth: 2,
    visible: true,
    hintLayout: HintLayout
  });
  myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject4);
  //Оформление Пина
  MyIconContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
      '<div style="color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold;">$[properties.iconContent]</div>'
    ),

    myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([60.017089596047725, 30.434473], {
      hintContent: 'Мы находимся тут',
    }, {
      // Опции.
      iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
      //прописать путь до пина
      iconImageHref: 'https://sandbox.api.maps.yandex.net/examples/ru/2.1/icon_customImage/images/myIcon.gif',
      iconImageSize: [20, 31],
      iconImageOffset: [-5, -38],
      iconContentLayout: MyIconContentLayout,
      hintLayout: HintLayout

    });

  myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

}

function setVisible() {
  myGeoObject4.options.set({
    visible: false
  });
  myGeoObject3.options.set({
    visible: false
  });
  myGeoObject2.options.set({
    visible: false
  });
  myGeoObject.options.set({
    visible: false
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#change-map').on('click', function() {
    setVisible();
  });
});
```